# How to order a factor variable within shinyapp

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

Within the shiny framework, I am trying to create an interactive table. As it is shown in this screenshot the age variable is not ordered. [image: screenshot] How can I fix this?

I tried the following code to order the age group variable but did not work.

```
 workforce_t <- workforce 

output$workforce_table_1 <- renderTable ({

  #sort the age_group variable
  workforce_t$Age_Group <- factor(
    workforce_t$Age_Group,
    levels = c(
      "16+",
      "16 to 24",
      "25 to 34",
      "35 to 44",
      "45 to 54",
      "55 to 64",
      "65+"
    ),
    labels = c(
      "16+",
      "16 to 24",
      "25 to 34",
      "35 to 44",
      "45 to 54",
      "55 to 64",
      "65+"
    )
  )

  info <- reactive ({
    out <- workforce_t %>%
      filter (County %in% input$county_workforce,
              #Year %in% input$years,
              Indicator %in% input$Indicator_workforce)
    return(out)

  })
  (info())
})
```

Thanks,

Nader

Answer (score 0):

We can add an `arrange` statement for 'County', 'Age_Group'.  As the 'Age_Group' is already a `factor` with `levels` specified, it would order based on the `levels`.  Also, the assignment and `return` is optional.  It can be made compact by removing those

```
info <- reactive({
   workforce_t %>%
      filter (County %in% input$county_workforce,
              #Year %in% input$years,
              Indicator %in% input$Indicator_workforce) %>%
      arrange(County, Age_Group)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Your codes creates an error: cannot coerce class ‘c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")’ to a data.frame

Comment: @NaderMehri. Can you please show a small reproducible example a I can't test your code